# DBUS Error on Kiosk-like Machine

Tags: 14.04, gnome, xorg, dbus, totem

I have an Ubuntu 14.04.3 mini-PC (w/latest v4 kernel) that's used as a digital signage controller. I have two versions of this: an early one (that's causing trouble) and the latest one (which works perfectly). I'm trying to write an update script/patch that brings some of the early ones (already in the field) up to speed with the latest/working version.

For both early and later units, I initially installed the *server* flavor of Ubuntu. For the early version, I then installed the Gnome Desktop environment from repo to get graphical capabilities. But on the later version, I just installed X-windows and a basic window manager from the beginning (no Gnome, whatsoever)... it was a learning experience, and I didn't want to refactor a lot of proprietary code, so don't laugh too hard!

So, for the early version's patch/script, I use `apt-get` to remove and purge all of the Gnome Desktop environment, and then to install X and matchbox all over again from repo... basically, mimicking the procedure I used to get the later version working (to the best of my memory). Still, I don't seem to have it exactly right.

The unit is supposed to show PowerPoints, plays videos, show web pages, etc. The **only** thing that doesn't work is the video playback. For that, I build a customized version of Totem/Gstreamer. The exact same versions run on both the early units and the later units. The trouble I'm seeing is that my video player is crashing with the following going to the apport.log in /var/log:

```
ERROR: apport (pid 3751) Fri Nov  4 12:17:24 2016: executable: /usr/bin/totem (command line "/usr/local/bin/totem --fullscreen --loop /home/kio/video/test.mp4
ERROR: apport (pid 3751) Fri Nov  4 12:17:24 2016: is_closing_session(): no DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in environment
ERROR: apport (pid 3751) Fri Nov  4 12:17:24 2016: apport: report /var/crash/_usr_bin_totem.1000.crash already exists and unseen, doing nothing to avoid disk usage DoS
```

To confuse me further, if I SSH into the machine as root, do an export of DISPLAY, and then open Totem manually, it plays just fine. It's only when it's opened via the processes (below) that it crashes.

FYI, I have two relevant users involved: root and kio. Most things run as the root user (I had little choice to avoid refactoring all of this inherited code), but the machines are secured well enough, so please spare the lectures! :)

Here are some relevant processes:

```
root      1334  0.0  0.1  14540  2112 tty1     Ss+  12:16   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
root      1373  0.0  0.2  21092  4992 tty2     S+   12:16   0:00 -bash
root      1389  0.0  0.0  16004   936 tty2     S+   12:16   0:00 xinit -- -nocursor
root      1390  0.0  2.2 151812 44500 tty7     S<s+ 12:16   0:03 X :0 -nocursor
root      1394  0.0  0.4  86064  8800 tty2     S    12:16   0:00 matchbox-window-manager
root      1652  0.0  0.3  30976  6244 tty2     S    14:00   0:00 /home/kio/bin/controller
root      2759  0.0  0.1  61680  3216 tty2     S    14:00   0:00 su kio -c /usr/local/bin/totem --fullscreen --loop "/home/kio/video/test.mp4" 
kio       2760  4.0  0.8 308236 17612 ?        Ssl  14:00   0:00 /usr/local/bin/totem --fullscreen --loop /home/kio/video/test.mp4
```

Another FYI.. as you can see, I just have a TTY automatically login as root, and then the root user's `bashrc` and `xinitrc` files take care of starting stuff from there. The `controller` process is a proprietary program that takes care of starting Totem or whatever the sign is supposed to show, killing processes, etc.

The later version runs the exact same processes, but doesn't complain about DBUS... so, what am I missing?? I've tried all I could find on Google about setting variables and such, but nothing works.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because custom kernels are off-topic here.

Comment: Would be fine over on [unix.se] :)

Comment: Not true... I'm using the stock Ubuntu kernel. I didn't say anything about using a custom kernel.

Comment: indeed - 14.04.5 ships with 4.4

Comment: @guntbert but OP states 14.04.3. Plus latest v4 kernel is stated which would be 4.8.6.

Comment: To be clear, I originally had 14.04.3 to work with, but didn't want to upset any apple carts, so didn't do the full 14.04.4 or .5 updates. Instead, I discretely updated just the kernel to better support some timing issues I was getting with some SIP stuff.

Comment: Did you try obtaining the rest of the updates to determine if that would solve your problems? There's no risk of upsetting apple carts provided you backup. You might image the current setup as an insurance policy. (I would)

Comment: Well, with the spaghetti I've inherited, I'm very wary about changing unnecessary things. I would prefer to distill down a specific cause of this DBUS business and fix it surgically rather than taking a blunt club to the problem. Sure, if that's not possible, I may have to try all the updates as a last resort. But I really would like to understand what's going on, too.